# В чем отличие getExternalFilesDir от getExternalStorageDir?

Tags: java, android

В чем отличие `getExternalFilesDir` от `getExternalStorageDir`???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Метод `getExternalFilesDir(...)` возвращает объект класса `File`, позиционируемый по пути `Android/data/data/%APP_PACKAGE_NAME%/` в *primary shared/external storage*.

Метод `getExternalStorageDirectory()` возвращает объект класса `File`, позиционируемый по пути (примерно) `mnt/sdcard/` (путь к *primary shared/external storage*).

Answer (score 7):

В Android есть несколько типов хранилищ, на которых могут храниться файлы: внутреннее (internal storage), основное внешнее (primary external storage), дополнительное внешнее (seconday external storage).

Основное внешнее хранилище - это дополнительная SD-карта или часть встроенной флэш-памяти, выделенная в отдельную файловую систему. Эта файловая система доступна для чтения и записи приложениям. Путь к корню основного внешнего хранилища можно получить с помощью [getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()).

Операционная система для своих нужд может создавать каталоги на основном внешнем хранилище. В частности на нем создаются каталоги для данных приложений. Структура этих каталогов от версии к версии и от устройства к устройству может меняться, поэтому для удобства разработчикам предоставлени функция [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)), которая возвращает путь к каталогу приложения на внешнем хранилище. При необходимости этот каталог будет создан операционной системой.

У функции `getExternalFilesDir()` есть параметр, в котором можно указать тип данных, которые предполагается хранить: [DIRECTORY_PICTURES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_PICTURES), [DIRECTORY_MUSIC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_MUSIC) и т.д. Для каждого типа данных будет создан свой каталог.

Обратите внимание, что работа с данными в каталоге `getExternalFilesDir()` на Android старше 4.4 (SDK меньше 18) требует разрешения:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

Работа с остальными каталогами внешнего хранилища требует разрешения всегда. Причем это разрешение "опасное", поэтому начиная с SDK 23 его необходимо запрашивать у пользователя и проверять результат (но это тема отдельного рассказа).

Советую прочитать еще раз "Руководство", [там есть целый раздел](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).

Если сложно с английским, в разделе "Курсы" есть [рассказ на русском про работу с файлами](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html).

Comment: Наоборот, работа с данными в каталоге `getExternalFilesDir()` начиная с API level 19 не требует разрешения `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`: «Starting in Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT, no permissions are required to read or write to the returned path».